# Data in a display form disappears/replaced when paging through a form webpart

Tags: 2010, list, data-view-web-part, out-of-the-box

I have a list of Organisations, and webparts within the form related to an Organisation (i.e Complaints webpart, Policies webpart and Correspondence webpart). If there are over 10 complaints against the organisation, the webpart pages any complaints above 10. If I want to see any complaint above 10 in the webpart, the data in the form disappears and is replaced by SharePoint data (description of a column or displays todays date if it's a date column).

I've done some testing on our test site, this issue still appears even if there's only 1 webpart and no connections/filter between the webpart and the list. This is an example of what appears when I page through a webpart (the default first page does not affect the data in the form):

Event Title: Event Title field value.
Location: Location field value.
Start Time: 04/03/2014 12:40
End Time: 04/03/2014 12:40
All Day Event: Yes
Recurrence: No
Workspace: No
Attendees: Attendees field value.
Approval Status: Approved Approver Comments field value.

Has anyone come across something similar? Is there a solution?

Thanks